# Convert Date string into another string with different format

Tags: java, string, date, simpledateformat, date-formatting

I'm quite new to the Java and for the use case I would like to know how to convert String "2023-02-01" into "02012023"
I had troubles understanding the correct usage of SimpleDateFormat for this case

So far I tried nothing

Comment: "I had troubles understanding the correct usage of SimpleDateFormat for this case" - do you *have* to use that class at all? I'd strongly recommend using java.time, e.g. `java.time.LocalDate` to represent a date. Basically, you should parse the existing string into a `LocalDate`, and then format it into the format. `DateTimeFormatter` is the appropriate class to use for that.

Comment: The most correct way to use `SimpleDateFormat` is - *not* to use it at all. Seriously. That class is so troublesome and so long outdated, you will never want to use it. See the answer.

Comment: I am wondering a bit about the format you say you want, `02012023`. I don't imagine anyone wanting to read a date in that format. What do you want it for? Wouldn't your users want something more readable and unambiguous?

Comment: @OleV.V. this is how date is stored on the backend, users are seeing in different format

Comment: That explains, or halfway, thanks. It’s also a non-recommended format for storage. If your storage doesn’t directly support a date type, I recommend storing as a string in [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), for example -- yes the format you have already got! `2023-02-01`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat` is legacy now, try to use the modern `java.time` library instead:

```
String newStringDate = LocalDate.parse("2023-02-01")
        .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMdduuuu"));
```